# How do I query these three specific tables for information with inner joins?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

> customers- with columns customer_id (Primary key), first_name,
>   middle_name,  last_name, email (Unique), password, first_visit.
>
> products- with columns product_id (Primary Key), product_name
>   (Unique), safety_warning, company.
>
> purchases- with columns purchase_id (Primary key), customer_id
>   (foreign key), product_id (foreign key), date.

How would I produce a list of all purchases with 1 specific company, e.g. "Company1", showing: the first_name of the customers, the product_name,  and the safety_warning for that product that the customers have bought. Would I use inner joins?

Comment: What if a customer purchases more than one product?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to perform two inner joins on both the `purchases` and `products` tables.

```
SELECT c.first_name, pr.product_name, pr.safety_warning
FROM CUSTOMERS c
INNER JOIN PURCHASES pu
ON c.customer_id = pu.customer_id
INNER JOIN products pr
ON pr.product_id = pu.product_id
WHERE pr.company = "Company 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, products.product_name, products.safety_warning
FROM customers JOIN purchases JOIN products 
ON (customers.customer_id = purchases.customer_id AND
products.product_id = purchases.product_id)
WHERE company = "Company1"
```

should work

Comment: if you find it appropriate, you can upvote or/and mark this or another answer as solution, so your question is marked as closed

Comment: Why are there no semicolons?

Comment: MySQL does not need them if you only have one statement. You can add one semicolon at the end of the entire statement, if you wish to make more statements. If you insert some semicolons here in between, the code will fail

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well You have a lot of options now.

```
SELECT C.first_name, PR.product_name, PR.safety_warning 
FROM purchases PU
join products PR on PU.product_id =PR.product_id 
join customers C on PU.customer_id =C.customer_id 
where PR.company="COMPANY1"
```